# Link to Active forms in tabs Yii2

Tags: tabs, yii2-advanced-app

Below code creates two tabs, I want one tab to open create page of the machine controller and the other to open the index page of the same machine controller.

```
<?= Tabs::widget([
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'One', 
            'icon' => 'user',
            'content' => $this->render('index1', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]),
            'active' => true
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Two',
            'content' =>$this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,

    ]),

        ],

    ],
]);
?>
```

So, as of now i could able to link to the index page( Tab One) but I'm not able to display the create form in tab Two.

This is what I have tried

```
'content' =>$this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,

    ]),
```

But I'm getting error as below

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Undefined variable: model

How can make it to display the create form under tab two?

Comment: Error says undefined variable!!! .. are you sending that variable on the tab page ?

Comment: yes, I have updated the tab page code in question, included create page in tab

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, I had include both index and create action logic under single action, say actionTab,